# Symfony best practice for data export file location

Tags: symfony

I am writing a console command which generates data files to be used by external services (for example, a Google feed, inventory feed, etc).  Should the location of the generated data files be within the Symfony app? I know they can actually be anywhere, I'm just wondering if there is a standard way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to you, but it is better to have this path in a parameter. For example you can you have a parameter group related to your command. This allows you to have different configurations depending on the current environment:

```
parameters:
    # /app/config.yml 
    # @see MyExportCommand.php
    my_export_command:
        base_path:       '/data/ftp/export'
        other_command_related_param: true
```

In your command, get and store those parameters in the `initialize` function:

```
// MyExportCommand.php
protected function initialize(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $this->parameters = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('my_export_command');
}
```

Finally in your execute function, you can use something like this: (`$this->fs` is an instance of the [Symfony2 Filesystem component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html))

```
// execute()
// Write the file
$filePath = $this->parameters['base_path']. '/'. $this->fileName;
$this->fs->dumpFile($filePath, $myContent);
```

Comment: The Symfony docs that you shouldn't write any files within a bundle directory. "The bundle directory is read-only. If you need to write temporary files, store them under the cache/ or log/ directory of the host application. Tools can generate files in the bundle directory structure, but only if the generated files are going to be part of the repository."

Comment: So? The base_path I gave is not in your Symfony bundle. Moreover the data you need to export are not temporary files, so they shouldn't go inside `cache` obviously.